# How CSS property "opacity" renders in browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera)?

Tags: css, browser

I have noticed, there is a color change for modal dialogs while "fadeIn" effect is applied.
So, wanted to know, how exactly CSS property "opacity" renders in the browsers?

Can anybody please explain that how different browsers renders CSS opacity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in old Internet explorer browsers.. opacity is rendered as nothing!

Comment: Older IE (<=8) will use filters instead of opacity.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić, Thanks for your reply. But I want to know HOW browsers CSS rendering engine works for CSS property "opacity".

Comment: Opacity is done with an *average* operation with the pixel value that's behind with weightage based on the value of opacity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opacity is done with an *average* operation with the pixel value that's behind with weight-age based on the value of opacity.

For example if you have a pixel

`R: 200, G: 220, B: 100` at `10, 10`

And you want to render an element with a background color of `150, 120, 100` and `opacity: 0.5` over it, the resultant pixel color will be calculated as:

```
opacity = 0.5

R = 200 * (1-opacity) + 150 * opacity
G = 220 * (1-opacity) + 120 * opacity
B = 100 * (1-opacity) + 100 * opacity
```

The above calculation will be performed (likely at hardware level) for all pixels the translucent element falls over.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how browsers render it.. But i know that all Elements inside the one that has the opacity property will be affected too.

Hope this helps you.